# react-router-dom v4. <BrowserRouter/> wrapper - does it need to be included in App tree?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

So, I have observed one interesting thing when I uses the `<BrowserRouter>` wrapper inside my `App` structure. It does not fires location change (`@@router/LOCATION_CHANGE`) action dispatch on each location change and does not update `location` props in `router` object inside `Redux` `store`, only fires on initial mount instead.

So there is how my App structure looks like:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { ConnectedRouter } from 'connected-react-router';

const AppContainer = ({ store, history }) => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
        <BrowserRouter> // that is one is blocking action location dispatch
          <AppLayout>
              <Switch location={location}>
                <Route exact path='/' component={HelloWorld} />
                <Route path='/next' component={StartCoding} />
              </Switch>
          </AppLayout>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </ConnectedRouter>
    </Provider>
  );
};
```

And interesting thing is, that if I fully remove the wrapper `<BrowserRouter>` from app structure the action dispatch  `@@router/LOCATION_CHANGE` fires normally...

Any one know what is this magic is and is it bad to remove it or not?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the "magic" involved, but I recommend that you use `<Router>` instead of `<BrowserRouter>` based on what is stated in the react-router API, which reads: "The most common use-case for using the low-level `<Router>` is to synchronize a custom history with a state management lib like Redux or Mobx." Here's the [link.](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Router.md) if you want to read more.

Comment: Hey, thank you for response. Btw you should know that `<BrowserRouter />` has replace the `Router` since react-router v4. So, it does not make sense...